# Problem while calculing the bending torque of internal air pressure in a soft actuator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, pressure, torque

this is a question I cant resolve while looking a paper I needed for my undergraduate thesis.

In this image (from *Modeling of Soft Fiber-Reinforced Bending Actuators, Panagiotis Polygerinos* et al.), you can see a similar actuator to the one I'm using in my work.
[image: Soft actuator diagram]

where $P_1$ is the internal aire pressure, $P_{atm}$ the atmospheric pressure, $a$ is the inner radius of the hemicylindrical air chamber with thickness $t$, and $b$ is the flat rectangular bottom layer thickness.

We want to calculate the bending torque of the internal air pressure against the distal cap of the actuator $M_a$ around the point $O$. In the paper I mentioned before, they solve this bending torque as:

$$
M_a = 2(P_1 - P_{atm})\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(a\cdot \sin\phi+ b)a^2 \cdot \cos^2 \phi d\phi \\ =\frac{4a^3 + 3\pi a^2 b}{6}(P_1 - P_{atm})
$$

My problem is that I do not understand the expressions they have put inside the integral for its solution. Where does that $(a\cdot \sin\phi+ b)a^2 \cdot \cos^2 \phi$ come from?

I'm sorry if that is a stupid question, I'm not skilled in math or physics... And thanks in advance.